# How to define decimal separator while exporting pandas dataframe to google sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-sheets, export

I have a bunch of excel files that need their content to be moved to google sheets. I am using python to read the excel file content into dataframe, and then upload the dataframe to a google sheet using pygsheets. The problem is that after exporting data, decimal separator in google sheet is a dot, which causes it to be interpreted as a string. Is there a way to define the separator to be comma or should i use different method?

Comment: maybe you should convert values to strings and replace dot with comma - and later export it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.